# xUnit test appears in "External" category and won't run normally

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xunit

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with xUnit 2 with the Visual Studio test runner. [I have this sample project that exhibits the following problem](https://github.com/jennings/so-41905497):

If I return `string`, `Task<string>` or `MyObject` from a method, the test appears in Test Explorer normally.

However, if I return `Task<MyObject>`, the test appears under an "External" category instead, and doesn't run when I click "Run Tests" in the editor.

[image: Test explorer with a test under the "External" category]

What could be causing this? I've found two Stack Overflow questions that sound similar, but they don't seem to apply:

- [This question suggests generating PDB files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702310/test-are-being-shown-under-external-category-in-test-explorer-when-grouped-by), but I am already generating them.
- [This question is nearly the same, but seems to be for ASP.NET Core, which I am not using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799380/xunit-async-tests-shows-up-as-external-in-vs2015)

Below is the information from Visual Studio's "About" page.

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update
>   3 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01586
>
> Installed Version: Professional
>
> LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA445 Microsoft
>   LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015
>   00322-40000-00000-AA445 Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications
>   2015
>
> Visual Basic 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA445 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2015
>
> Visual C# 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA445 Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Visual C++ 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA445 Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
>
> Visual F# 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA445 Microsoft Visual F# 2015
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   7.17.00119.9
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1   14.1.20907.0 ASP.NET and Web Tools
>   2015.1
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> Azure App Service Tools v2.8.1   14.0.11123.0 Azure App Service Tools
>   v2.8.1
>
> Breakpoint Generator   1.0 Automatically generate tracepoints for all
>   the public entry points in your solution.
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.8 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.2    Build 105.0.20160522.80219
>   JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For
>   more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit
>   http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2017 JetBrains, Inc.
>
> Markdown Editor   1.10.186 A full featured Markdown editor with live
>   preview and syntax highlighting. Supports GitHub flavored Markdown.
>
> Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 2)   14.1.20907.0 Microsoft .NET
>   Core Tools (Preview 2)
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4 Microsoft Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> NuGet Package Manager   3.5.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Analysis Services   13.0.1700.68 Microsoft SQL Server
>   Analysis Services Designer  Version 13.0.1700.68
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60812.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> SQL Server Integration Services    Microsoft SQL Server Integration
>   Services Designer Version 13.0.1601.5
>
> SQL Server Reporting Services   13.0.1700.68 Microsoft SQL Server
>   Reporting Services Designers  Version 13.0.1700.68
>
> TargetFrameworkMigrator   1.0 Bulk Change .Net Projects Target
>   Frameworks
>
> TypeScript   1.8.36.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   14.0.25420.01 The
>   Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a
>   single universal app experience that can reach every device running
>   Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft
>   Windows 10 Software Development Kit.
>
> VsVim   2.2.0.0 VsVim is a Vim emulator for Visual Studio
>
> Web Essentials 2015.3   3.0.235 Adds many useful features to Visual
>   Studio for web developers. Requires Visual Studio 2015
>
> Windows Installer XML Toolset   3.10.3.3007 Windows Installer XML
>   Toolset version 3.10.3.3007 Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and
>   contributors. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had several tests mysteriously labelled as "external" when using `async Task<MyObject>` calls. My workaround was to define `MyObject` inside the test assembly instead. Clearly this is not a solution for all cases, but it worked for me because I'm just de-serializing JSON data to POCO objects inside these problematic async function calls.